# How to load KML file in browser

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, kml

I have to load KML file in browser.And I have load simple KML file it works perfectly but when I upload the KML file with multiple folder for images it is not loading properly.
Code of line used:-

```
               <div id="map_canvas"></div>
                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false>"></script>
                <script>
                    var mylocation = {
                        'latitude':  -45.2427303,
                        'longitude': 115.0639984
                    };
                    var map;
                    function initialize() 
                    {
                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( mylocation.latitude, mylocation.longitude );
                        var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 5,
                            center: myLatlng,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        }
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

                        var kmlPath = '<?php echo urldecode($file_name)?>';

                        var urlSuffix = (new Date).getTime().toString();
                        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlPath + '?' + urlSuffix );
                        layer.setMap(map);
                    }
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                </script>
```

Comment: What does the KML file look like?  How big is it?  Is it [valid](http://www.feedvalidator.org/)?  Is `kmlPath` a fully qualified URL? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

KMLLayer generates map tiles in Google's server side. For the reason, multiple KMLLayer (and fusion tables layer also) do not work as you expected sometimes.
This is not described in the official document, but this comes from my experience.

I recommend you use GeoJSON with DataLayer.
DataLayer generates overlays (marker, polyline , etc...) in client side.
And you can modify the generated overlays easily.
Check it out.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#overview